# Found candidate encoder OMX.allwinner.video.encoder.avc, but not setup encoder

Tags: android, video, encoder

I am trying to encode video-stream record from my camera and encode them into h264 by using some kind of HW encoder on my board(orange pi prime) but some how it could not work functionally.

Here is the logcat:

```
01-16 17:19:35.459 1493-1493/? W/art: Verification of void 
android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.<init>(android.content.Context) took 250.281ms
01-16 17:19:35.533 1493-1802/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/jpeg
01-16 17:19:35.536 1493-1802/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mpeg1
01-16 17:19:35.538 1493-1802/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mpeg2
01-16 17:19:35.544 1493-1802/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
01-16 17:19:35.550 1493-1802/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-vnd.on2.vp6
01-16 17:19:35.557 1493-1802/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/wvc1
01-16 17:19:35.561 1493-1802/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-mpeg4v1
01-16 17:19:35.567 1493-1802/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-mpeg4v2
01-16 17:19:35.569 1493-1802/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
01-16 17:19:35.576 1493-1802/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/xvid
01-16 17:19:35.581 1493-1802/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/flv1
01-16 17:19:35.588 1493-1802/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/rvg2
01-16 17:19:35.595 1493-1802/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/wmv1
01-16 17:19:35.601 1493-1802/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/wmv2
01-16 17:19:35.657 1493-1802/? I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
01-16 17:19:35.685 1570-1625/? I/[Gralloc]: ion_alloc from ion_client:16 via heap type DMA(mask:16) for 1382400 Bytes cached buffer successfully, usage = 0x00000132
01-16 17:19:35.692 1493-1802/? V/MediaCodecVideoEncoder: Found candidate encoder OMX.allwinner.video.encoder.avc
01-16 17:19:35.692 1493-1802/? V/MediaCodecVideoEncoder: Found candidate encoder OMX.google.h264.encoder
01-16 17:19:35.705 1493-1802/? D/MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Trying to find HW decoder for mime video/avc
01-16 17:19:35.708 1493-1802/? D/MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found candidate decoder OMX.allwinner.video.decoder.avc
01-16 17:19:35.708 1493-1802/? D/MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found candidate decoder OMX.google.h264.decoder
01-16 17:19:35.708 1493-1802/? D/MediaCodecVideoDecoder: No HW decoder found for mime video/avc
01-16 17:19:35.732 1570-1625/? I/[Gralloc]: ion_alloc from ion_client:16 via heap type DMA(mask:16) for 136320 Bytes uncached buffer successfully, usage = 0x00000702
```

It seems like the program had found my HW encoders, but never setup them. I don't know how to fix this. any good ideas?